# Replace text of element that start with specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have html like bottom code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {name length='100'}
        </td>
        <td>
            {otherText length='100'}
        </td>
        <td>
            {otherText2 length='100'}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change `td`s text that start with `{name`.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to replace only `100` in that line or the whole line?

Comment: I know I can select the line with ("td:contains('name')"), but this is not specific enough. I need some kind of wildcard to match the text {name WITH curly braces.

Comment: @MartinDK81 Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the whole inner text that starts with `{name`, try this:

```js
// added this condition to have the startsWith function in all browsers
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        position = position || 0;
        return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
    };
}

function replace(newVal) {
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        var elem = tds[i];
        if ( elem.innerText.startsWith("{name") ) {
            elem.innerText = newVal;
        }
    }
}

replace("new-value");
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {name length='100'}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

As Mohammad mentioned, the `startsWith` method is not supported in all browsers. See the table below:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║    Feature    ║ Chrome ║ Firefox ║ Edge  ║ Internet Explorer ║ Opera ║ Safari ║
╠═══════════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ Basic Support ║     41 ║      17 ║ (Yes) ║ No Support        ║    28 ║      9 ║
╚═══════════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

This is why I added the condition above - to have the `startsWith` function in all browsers.

Comment: `startWith()` support in upper version of browser. For example version 41 of chrome. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `text(function)` to iterating all `td`s text and use `match()` to checking text content by regex.

```js
$("td").text(function(index, text){
    if (text.trim().match(/^{name/))
        return "Changed text";
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      {name length='100'}
    </td>
    <td>
      {type length='100'}
    </td>
    <td>
      {other length='100'}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('td').html('{name '+new_text);
```